# Keyword Arguments for C++

Tags: python, c++, keyword-argument

After programming in Python I got used to [Keyword Arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter).

They don't seem to work even as of C++11 (and aren't listed as supported in the "Use in Programming Languages" section of the link).

Is this something that has been purposed for C++?

Comment: No. I'd love that feature, but no.

Comment: Boost has a library for this and there are a couple proposals.

Comment: I think it would be a breaking change and definitely not worth it.

Comment: Wouldn't be a breaking change (`identifier:expression` cannot occur in function call expressions). The easier solution is to allow `,default,` in argument lists, with the obvious meaning.